# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.core.function.trace_type' has no attribute 'from_value'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

This one line python program fails with the error message above on windows 10 with python 310:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

Preceding the keras's with 'tensorflow.' does not help.

Edit 1: Seems like none of my pthon files that us tensorflow are now failing with this error. I must have installed something that is incompatible. How does one find out what the problem is?

Edit 2: Any import of tensorflow or keras gets a stack trace (please see below). They all seem to get intp module_util and end up in _make_function_type.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ray\eclisepython\2py\src\p\t.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
```

...

```
  File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\polymorphic_function\function_spec.py", line 272, in _make_function_type
    type_constraint = trace_type.from_value(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.core.function.trace_type' has no attribute 'from_value'



Package                      Version
---------------------------- -----------
absl-py                      1.3.0
altgraph                     0.17.2
anyio                        3.6.1
appdirs                      1.4.4
argon2-cffi                  21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings         21.2.0
arrow                        1.2.3
asgiref                      3.5.2
asttokens                    2.2.1
astunparse                   1.6.3
attrs                        22.2.0
backcall                     0.2.0
beautifulsoup4               4.11.1
bleach                       5.0.1
blosc2                       2.0.0
cachetools                   5.2.1
certifi                      2022.9.24
cffi                         1.15.1
charset-normalizer           2.1.1
click                        8.1.3
colorama                     0.4.5
comm                         0.1.2
contextvars                  2.4
contourpy                    1.0.6
cryptography                 39.0.0
cycler                       0.11.0
Cython                       0.29.33
dash                         2.7.1
dash-core-components         2.0.0
dash-html-components         2.0.0
dash-table                   5.0.0
debugpy                      1.6.5
decorator                    5.1.1
defusedxml                   0.7.1
entrypoints                  0.4
et-xmlfile                   1.1.0
executing                    1.2.0
fastjsonschema               2.16.2
finta                        1.3
Flask                        2.2.2
flatbuffers                  23.1.4
fonttools                    4.38.0
fqdn                         1.5.1
frozendict                   2.3.4
future                       0.18.2
gast                         0.4.0
google-auth                  2.16.0
google-auth-oauthlib         0.4.6
google-pasta                 0.2.0
grpcio                       1.51.1
h11                          0.13.0
h5py                         3.7.0
html5lib                     1.1
htmltools                    0.1.2
idna                         3.3
immutables                   0.18
ipykernel                    6.20.1
ipython                      8.8.0
ipython-genutils             0.2.0
ipywidgets                   8.0.4
isoduration                  20.11.0
itsdangerous                 2.1.2
jedi                         0.18.2
Jinja2                       3.1.2
joblib                       1.2.0
jsonpointer                  2.3
jsonschema                   4.17.3
jupyter                      1.0.0
jupyter_client               7.4.8
jupyter-console              6.4.4
jupyter_core                 5.1.3
jupyter-events               0.6.2
jupyter_server               2.0.6
jupyter_server_terminals     0.4.4
jupyterlab-pygments          0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets           3.0.5
keras                        2.10.0
Keras-Preprocessing          1.1.2
kiwisolver                   1.4.4
libclang                     15.0.6.1
linkify-it-py                2.0.0
lxml                         4.9.2
Markdown                     3.4.1
markdown-it-py               2.1.0
MarkupSafe                   2.1.1
matplotlib                   3.6.2
matplotlib-inline            0.1.6
mdurl                        0.1.1
mistune                      2.0.4
msgpack                      1.0.4
multitasking                 0.0.11
nbclassic                    0.4.8
nbclient                     0.7.2
nbconvert                    7.2.7
nbformat                     5.7.2
nest-asyncio                 1.5.6
notebook                     6.5.2
notebook_shim                0.2.2
numexpr                      2.8.4
numpy                        1.24.2
oauthlib                     3.2.2
openpyxl                     3.1.0
opt-einsum                   3.3.0
packaging                    21.3
pandas                       1.5.3
pandas-datareader            0.10.0
pandocfilters                1.5.0
parso                        0.8.3
patsy                        0.5.3
pefile                       2022.5.30
pickleshare                  0.7.5
Pillow                       9.4.0
pip                          23.0
platformdirs                 2.6.2
plotly                       5.11.0
prometheus-client            0.15.0
prompt-toolkit               3.0.36
protobuf                     3.19.6
psutil                       5.9.3
pure-eval                    0.2.2
py-cpuinfo                   9.0.0
py4j                         0.10.9.5
pyasn1                       0.4.8
pyasn1-modules               0.2.8
pycparser                    2.21
Pygments                     2.14.0
pyinstaller                  5.3
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib    2022.8
pyparsing                    3.0.9
pyrsistent                   0.19.3
pyspark                      3.3.1
python-dateutil              2.8.2
python-json-logger           2.0.4
python-multipart             0.0.5
pytz                         2022.7
pywin32                      305
pywin32-ctypes               0.2.0
pywinpty                     2.0.10
PyYAML                       6.0
pyzmq                        24.0.1
qtconsole                    5.4.0
QtPy                         2.3.0
requests                     2.28.1
requests-oauthlib            1.3.1
rfc3339-validator            0.1.4
rfc3986-validator            0.1.1
rsa                          4.9
scikit-learn                 1.2.0
scipy                        1.10.0
seaborn                      0.12.2
Send2Trash                   1.8.0
setuptools                   63.2.0
shiny                        0.2.4
simplejson                   3.18.1
six                          1.16.0
sniffio                      1.2.0
soupsieve                    2.3.2.post1
stack-data                   0.6.2
starlette                    0.20.4
statsmodels                  0.13.5
tables                       3.8.0
tenacity                     8.1.0
tensorboard                  2.10.1
tensorboard-data-server      0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow                   2.11.0
tensorflow-estimator         2.10.0
tensorflow-intel             2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.29.0
termcolor                    2.2.0
terminado                    0.17.1
Theano                       1.0.5
threadpoolctl                3.1.0
tinycss2                     1.2.1
tornado                      6.2
traitlets                    5.8.1
typing_extensions            4.3.0
uc-micro-py                  1.0.1
uri-template                 1.2.0
urllib3                      1.26.12
uvicorn                      0.18.2
watchdog                     2.1.9
wcwidth                      0.2.5
webcolors                    1.12
webencodings                 0.5.1
websocket-client             1.4.2
websockets                   10.3
Werkzeug                     2.2.2
wheel                        0.38.4
widgetsnbextension           4.0.5
wrapt                        1.14.1
xgboost                      1.7.3
yahoo-finance                1.4.0
yfinance                     0.2.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your script up like it's described in the keras [docs](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/)

***edit:*** Alright, my next recommendation would be to create a new virtual environment and try installing your packages there and run your one line import and see if it works. It seems like there could be some issues with your current installed packages. Open up command prompt:

```
mkdir venvFolder             
cd venvFolder
python3 -m venv testVenv 
cd testVenv\Scripts
activate
```

You should now see `(testVenv)` in front of your prompt. Now:

```
(testVenv) C:\> pip3 install tensorflow
(testVenv) C:\> pip3 install keras
(testVenv) C:\> python3
```

Now that you have python open:

```py
>>> from keras.models import Sequential
>>> exit()
```

If the above runs without throwing an error, your next step would be:

```
(testVenv) C:\> deactivate
C:\> pip3 uninstall keras tensorflow
C:\> pip3 install keras tensorflow
```

*It's very important that you `deactivate` your virtual environment or you will be using the wrong pip for packages.*

Then try running your import again in whatever you were originally using to run your script and see if it works now.

Comment: that's a good idea, unfortunately it still fails. please see edit 2.

Comment: @RayTayek thanks for giving it a try, I added a new edit to my original answer in response to your edit. Please see if you have any success with that. I'm curious if isolating your attempts in a virtual environment will help.

Comment: that let import tensorflow and keras from the command line. i do not get a (<env>) on win 10. this requires a path to the env which is a bit of a hassle. thanks

Comment: uninstall/reinstall worked. got into trouble tryin g t o use theano. thanks.